# How to know about DB health from "Table_locks_immediate" and "Table_locks_waited" in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, table-locking

How to know the health of the mysql db by seeing the "Table_locks_immediate" and "Table_locks_waited" values from DB status.

I want to know if the ratio between "Table_locks_immediate" and "Table_locks_waited" is of any importance.

Answer (score -2):

You may learn something from :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html.

and

http://www.mysqlperformancetuning.com/how-to-speed-up-mysql-by-optimization

Comment: Please provide the answer (explanation) instead of just sharing the links.